# how do i make my targeted input push content up ionic

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

Guys can someone help me, I can't in any way get the content to push up when I target an input field. It covers the fields and everything below it, I tried every possible solution online, not once has anything been even a little bit changed, wtf is this? how to fix it? It just doesn't recognize any code that has to do with keyboard or pushing content up or input field it's so annoying

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? I didn't get it,

Comment: please post your question with code and how are you trying todo and what errors or issues you are facing so that other developers can understand your question and provide some solution

Comment: Well I have input fields in my app, and when I click on input field, the keyboard covers EVERYTHING even the input field if it's in the way of the keyboard. How do I fix this? I tried everything, the keyboard addon, custom animations everything but literally nothing works it won't even move